# Пунктуация при повторяющихся частицах "то"

Tags: запятые

Верно ли я поставила запятую перед первой частицей ***"то"*** в следующей фразе?

> Я люблю твой характер, то милый, то взрывной.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Знаки препинания расставлены верно:

**Я люблю твой харАктер, то мИлый, то взрывнОй.**

Это однородные определения, связанные повторяющимся союзом ТО...ТО, **которые в общем случае обособляются в позиции после определяемого слова** (как и любые другие определения).

Определение может не обособляться, если на него **переносится логическое ударение и отсутствует пауза** между определением и определяемым словом, но к приведенному примеру это не относится.

Обособление делается **по правилам Розенталя** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

6. Обособляются два или более одиночных (нераспространенных) определения, **стоящих после существительного,** если последнему предшествует еще одно (или несколько) определение....При отсутствии предшествующего определения **последующие одиночные определения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от степени их интонационно-смысловой близости с определяемым существительным.** А запорожцы, и пешие и конные, выступали на три дороги к трём воротам (Г.);

**А как же союз ТО...ТО?** Это повторяющийся союз, а для повторяющихся союзов  **специальных правил обособления не предусмотрено.**

Примеры:

Конечно, смех, **то веселый, то горький,** уже четвертое столетие раздающийся в театрах всего мира. [К. И. Чуковский. Высокое искусство (1968)]

Мне стан твой понравился тонкий
И весь твой задумчивый вид,
А смех твой, **и грустный и звонкий,**
С тех пор в моем сердце звучит (А. Толстой).

**По поводу остальных знаков.** Двоеточие и тире здесь — это авторские варианты. Тире обозначает присоединительную конструкцию, двоеточие — пояснительную, но всё это дополнительные значения, которые не являются очевидно оправданными.

**Комментарий (все ли правила правильные)**

Правил в Сети много, поэтому надо отличать правила правильные от неправильных. **Розенталь и ПАС** — это наши основные официальные источники информации, к ним можно добавить материалы Грамоты.ру, да и то осторожно. А вот с другими правилами нужно общаться как можно меньше, потому что это не правила, а их толкования.  И применять их надо умеючи.

Яркий пример — это рассмотренное здесь **правило о союзе ТО...ТО.** [https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/704/то](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/704/%D1%82%D0%BE)…_то…

Ну какое отношение к обособленным определениям имеют приведенные там примеры, отнесенные к  однородным сказуемым, обстоятельствам или дополнениям? Разумеется, никакого.  Поэтому обобщение по поводу союза ТО...ТО совершенно неправомерно и имеет **частный характер.**

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в Правилах о тире (https://therules.ru/dash/#175) прямого указания нет,  применительно к вашему случаю подходит §176, который гласит:

> Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой, которая
>   отделяет главное предложение от предшествующей ему группы придаточных,
>   если надо подчеркнуть распадение единого целого на две части,
>   например: *Кто виноват из них, кто прав, — судить не нам (Крылов).*

*Я люблю твой характер, — то милый, то взрывной.*

(Где *то*..., *то*... это союз: то он, то я; то здесь, то там.)

Comment: Я бы тоже предпочёл тире, но думаю, что запятая перед ним не нужна.

Comment: Поначалу и я тоже. Запятая здесь — может быть, может не быть — от настроения и контекста зависит.

Comment: @shampar *>> Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой, которая отделяет главное предложение от предшествующей ему группы придаточных* – где здесь предшествующая группа придаточных?

Comment: В Вашем примере всё наоборот как раз: распадение в левой части предложения, а у автора — в правой. Это-то и меняет знак на другой (пояснение, затем обобщение или наоборот).

Comment: И начал с того, что пункт Правил (пример оттуда же) не в полной мере соответствует случаю, но порядок здесь не суть главное. Решает контекст: эта фраза может как начинать, так и завершать рассуждение.

Answer (score 1):

[**то... то...**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/704/%D1%82%D0%BE%E2%80%A6_%D1%82%D0%BE%E2%80%A6), союз
Если повторяющийся союз **то... то...** соединяет однородные члены предложения, то запятая ставится **перед вторым** и следующими членами предложения.
*Воза с кладью сидели по нескольку часов **то** в пропитанном вешней водой снегу, **то** на голых местах, где чернела земля* (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк. С голоду).

Очень хочется поставить запятую перед первым "то", но по правилам она там не нужна.
**Я люблю твой характер то милый, то взрывной.**

Если есть желание выделить однородные определения, сделать на них акцент, то можно поставить интонационное тире.
**Я люблю твой характер — то милый, то взрывной.**

> *В Полотняной стране
>
>   По реке Простыне
>
>   Плывет пароход
>
>   **То** назад, **то** вперед.
>
>   А за ним такая гладь —
>
>   Ни морщинки не видать!*
>   С. Маршак. В Полотняной стране...

**Дополнение**

*@Sharon* в своем ответе дает хорошую — правильную! — ссылку. А там есть и такие разъяснения (п. 6).
Однако если **предшествующее** определение выражено **местоимением**  [в нашем предложении — **твой**], то последующие определения могут не обособляться:
*И сон, и сладостный покой… посетили снова м о й у г о л **тесный и простой*** (П.).

Мы ведь можем обозначить логическое ударение на любом слове — все зависит от контекста (а его нет) и авторского восприятия.
Я ощутила так: **Я люблЮ твой характер то милый, то взрывной.**

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Очень хочется поставить запятую перед первым "то", но по правилам она там не нужна. **Я люблю твой характер то милый, то взрывной**._ === По-моему, плохой вариант. Обратите внимание на наличие определения **перед** словом "характер"...

Comment: Без союза: _Я люблю твой характер [—] милый, взрывной._ Здесь нет места для ещё одной запятой. Определение "твой" не является однородным по отношению к двум другим. Я вижу ТАК.

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: Без союза: **Я люблю твой характер [—] милый, взрывной**. Здесь нет места для ещё одной запятой_. === А я и не говорю, что здесь нужна запятая. "Плохим вариантом" чуть выше я назвал предложенный Вами вариант вообще без какого-либо знака препинания перед первым "то": **Я люблю твой характер то милый, то взрывной**. Может, я и неправ...

Comment: @Aer Ой, опять меня кто-то _бесследно_ наказал. Любопытно — за что такие привилегии?

Comment: Вы с Sharon меня в конец запутали. Если это Вы по поводу минуса выше говорите, то это был не минус, это я свой плюс переставил Sharon (но я это в первый раз за всё время, а не "опять"). Ладно, сейчас вернул плюс обратно, хотя это глупо голосовать за два противоречивых ответа :)

Comment: Опять — ой! Вообще-то я писала модератору... Но я Вас тоже не понимаю: КАК можно что-то (плюс-минус) бесследно "переставить"? Да ладно...

Answer (score 0):

Перед первым *"то"* лучше поставить двоеточие, поскольку во второй части содержится пояснение, можно вставить союз *"а именно":*

> Я люблю твой характер: то милый, то взрывной.

Answer (score 0):

Знаки расставлены верно. Двоеточие вместо запятой больше подходит к книжному стилю речи, которого здесь явно не наблюдается.